# Tcl WrongNumArgs standard error info into local

Tags: tcl

How to passing a standard error message into local message  if i use proc Name without arguments

I want decalre my own error information instead of global error message like

```
proc adder {a b} { 
    global errorInfo 
    puts "The stack trace was this:\n$errorInfo" 
    puts "I got an error in an event: adder arguments $a $b" 
}
```

->

```
adder
Error: wrong # args: should be "adder a b"
# (TCL) (this one is Standard error message)
```

i need above error message should be "`Error in selecting arguments ex: adder a b`"

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to achieve. The [`bgerror`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/bgerror.htm) command is *not* meant to be executed directly -- it's invoked by the interpreter which detected an error in a script which was executed by that interpreter as a callback attached to some event source (such as "file is readable" or "user clicked a button"). There's no point in calling this command by hand. But if you do, supply it a single argument -- the message.

Answer (score 0):

To get custom argument handling with a procedure, use `args` to capture all arguments and then do the processing yourself.

```
proc adder {args} {
    if {[llength $args] != 2} {
        return -code error "Error in selecting arguments ex: adder a b"
    }
    lassign $args a b
    # ...
}
```

If you're using Tcl 8.4, use this instead of `lassign $args a b`:

```
foreach {a b} $args break
```

(You could use an empty body instead of `break`, but it's a good habit to get into in case you've got more arguments than you expect. It won't happen here because of the `llength` check, but good habits are good habits!)

Comment: Could you explain in this case  proc adder {{a ""} {b""}  args} {

Comment: @user3069844 That will satisfy `a` first, then `b`, and only what's left after that will be stored in `args`